# How best to set up individual and family membership in our organization

Tags: civimember

We are using Wordpress and have CiviCRM version 5.39.0. I consider myself novice in website building.

I'm interested to know how best to set up 2 memberships in our organization, i.e. individual and family (both having different membership fees). Family will include spouse and all children (under 18) in the household.

I created a contribution page and was able to add 2 radio buttons for the individual membership or family membership sign up/renew option. However, the "profile" only list the individual membership signup/renew information (i.e. only personal information for a single person). It would be nice if  the "profile" can be updated to to show additional field for spouse and/or children information, when that radio button for family membership is selected. How can I do that?

Alternatively, how best would you suggest to set up the membership structure in CiviCRM?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: family memberships does not have an easy answer in my experience. to provide a form where a 'family' can enter names of those who 'share' the membership generally requires a more complex form than civi can currently provide - and that means using the CMS capability such as Caldera Form integration to let you create a form that can create multiple contacts on the one page

Comment: As long as CiviCRM has been around and as long as people have been wanting a proper way to handle family memberships, I can't believe we are still unable to handle a family membership. This would seem pretty basic.

Comment: maybe the new work on Afform is a step towards being able to do this in vanilla civicrm